# How to hide certain taxonomy views from user?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have one general taxonomy view wich has this alias mask /taxonomy/term/%.

What I need is to hide views for certain taxonomy terms like 'canada' from display while it'll remain showing the other ones the same way it was before.

Comment: Do you only want to control who can see certain pages, or do you want to disable that path for certain terms overall?

Comment: @prkos I would like to hide article teasers from users by role for certain taxonomy term. And if it's not possible, disabling path for terms would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Views only has 2 different types of access management:

- Via role
- Via permission

However, it's an all-or-nothing control; you can't do it on a per contextual argument basis (for a taxonomy in your `/taxonomy/term/%` view).

What you can do, is create your own Views access plugin (or perhaps one already exists, [look through drupal.org for 8.x Views projects](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=im_vid_3%3A89&f%5B3%5D=drupal_core%3A7234&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f%5B5%5D=&f%5B6%5D=&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search)). Take a look at the [access plugin code docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21access%21AccessPluginBase.php/group/views_access_plugins/8.6.x) or [this tutorial](http://www.badzilla.co.uk/drupal-8-views-custom-access-plugin) as primer on how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could edit the existing views and with some effort split the display into more than one page that would address each of the special terms individually it's not the most convenient way to go.

There are modules that can help you get there: [Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term). It doesn't only restrict access of the taxonomy term pages but the nodes as well. There is a documentation page with more information: [Documentation: Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/permissions-by-termhttps://).

If that doesn't help then try [Taxonomy Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_permissions) (not quite D8 ready) and/or [Taxonomy access fix](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix).